# Error: Could not locate bindings file node-librdkafka.node

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, debian-jessie

Suddenly I have started seeing below error while running a Node.js app using node-rdkafka. It was working before, not sure what triggered this error.

> Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried
>   -> /home/...../node-librdkafka.node  ...

I tried npm install, npm rebuild, all of them work without giving any issue, just that the bindings do not get created.

this is on debian-jessie guest in Virtual box running on Windows as host.

Thanks!

Comment: npm install node-rdkafka resolved this issue.

Answer (score 5):

npm install node-rdkafka resolved this issue.